# Survey.js : default value in a matrix of radiobutton

Tags: jquery, surveyjs

Good morning,

I got an issue with survey.js, I can't get to put a default value to my question, I want this :

[image]

but I get this :

[image]

with this code :

```
                questions: [
                {
                    name: "ph-avant",
                    type: "html",
                    html: "<img class='myImg' src='/Images/ParcMachine/Gaz/PartieAvant.jpg' />",
                },
                {
                    type: "panel",
                    title: "CONTROLE VISUEL",
                    startWithNewLine: scrW,
                    questions: [
                    {
                        name: "Avant",
                        type: "matrix",
                        isRequired: true,
                        isAllRowRequired: true,
                        defaultValue: "nc",
                        title: "Partie Avant",
                        columns: [
                            { value: "ok", text: "OK" },
                            { value: "ko", text: "NON OK" },
                            { value: "nc", text: "NON CONCERNE" }
                        ],
                        rows: [
                            { value: "Fourches", text: "Fourches", defaultValue: "nc" },
                            { value: "Phares", text: "Phare avant droit / gauche", defaultValue: "nc" },
                            { value: "Autres", text: "Mât / Pare brise / Essuie glace", defaultValue: "nc" },
                            { value: "Chaines", text: "Chaînes / Flexibles", defaultValue: "nc" },
                        ]
                    },
                        {
                            name: "obs_avant",
                            type: "comment",
                            title: "Observations",
                        }
                    ]
                },
            ]
```

I tried a lot of things for more than an hour, but even with chatGPT I can't figure out a way to make it work

thanks in advance

Comment: you need to set survey data

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up survey data with default values

```
survey.data = {Avant: 'nc'}
```

More information on the sample code [here](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/auto-populate-form-fields/jquery#content-code)

Comment: It probably should work, but it doesn't.

I put my survey n a let named survey, and then did survey.data as you suggested, but it still doesn't work

Comment: EDIT : tried to manipulate the Survey.Model object too, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can preset a question value by specifying the `survey.data` property or using the `survey.mergeData` function. For more information, refer to the following tutorial: [Populate Form Fields](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/design-survey/pre-populate-form-fields).

However, I encountered an exception when trying to set a NON CONCERNE option for the first matrix row. I forwarded the issue to the SurveyJS team for further investigation. You can track the progress in the following GitHub thread: [Single-Selection Matrix - Cannot create property 'Fourches' on string 'nc'](https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/issues/6629).

**[Update]**

To resolve the issue, please reset the default value for a matrix question. Now, you can predefine matrix answers by using the following code:

```
 survey.mergeData({
    Avant: {
      Fourches: "nc",
      Phares: "nc",
      Autres: "nc",
      Chaines: "nc"
    }
});
```

[View Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-currying-4nc4zy?file=/src/SurveyComponent.jsx:264-390)

Comment: The defaultValue for your matrix is incorrect. It should be an object and not a string. Please remove it or set it to a correct value:   defaultValue: "nc",